# Let $p(x) \in \mathbb{Z}[x], p(2) = p(-2) = 2, p(100) < 0$. Prove that $p(100) < -1000$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, polynomials

I have the following task:

> Let $p(x) \in \mathbb{Z}[x], p(2) = p(-2) = 2, p(100) < 0$. Prove that $p(100) < -1000$

I'v tried to make some substitutions, to factorize the polynomial, but didn't succeed and out of ideas now.
Can you give me some hints on what to try?

Comment: Hint:  consider the polynomial $q(x)=p(x)-2$.  Find a divisor of $q(x)$.

Comment: @lulu Thanks! I tried just that (i.e. defined $q(x) = p(x) - 2 = a_n(x-2)(x+2)f(x)$) but couldn't proceed from the point. But now I see, that it was the right trail. We know, that $f(100) \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $f(100) \neq 0$, so $p(100) = a_n \cdot 98 \cdot 100 \cdot f(100)$ is "rather big" (and the proceeding is now obvious). Is it right?

Comment: Ok, so $p(x)=(x^2-4)f(x)+2$.  We know $f(100)$ is an integer and it is easy to see that it is $<0$.  Hence $f(100)≤-1$.  Therefore...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

Use the fact that for any integers $x,y$ we have $$x-y\mid p(x)-p(y)$$

and mark $p(100)=a$. From a condition you get $a<0$ and ...

Comment: I accepted your post as an answer, because it was the only one, which was a hint and not a complete solution, but after the update I do not know what to do... :(

Comment: Yes, much better, thank you. Actually, I would not remove acceptance in either case, because your way to solve the task is better, but it's a rather philosophical question wheather full answers shouldn't be accepted when only a hint was asked for (and I do not know any inner rules of MSE which specifiy that)

Comment: @amWhy Thank you!

Comment: Glad to help, @Angle!

Answer (score 3):

.If $q(x) = p(x) - 2$, then $q(-2) = q(2) = 0$, so $q$ is a multiple of both $x-2$ and $x+2$, which are coprime hence $q$ is a multiple of $x^2 - 4$.

Consequently, $q(x) = (x^2 - 4)h(x)$ for some polynomial $h$ with integer coefficients. Substituting, $q(100)  = 9996 \times h(100)$, so $p(100) = 2 + 9996 \times h(100)$.

Note that $h(100)$ is an integer, so $p(100) = 2 + 9996k$, for some integer $k$. If $p(100) < 0$,  then $2 + 9996k < 0$, so $k < \dfrac{-2}{9996}$. Since $k$ is an integer, $k \leq -1$ , since this is the greatest integer smaller than $\dfrac {-2}{9996}$. Therefore,  $p(100) \leq 2 + 9996(-1) \leq -9994$.

It follows that $p(100) \leq -9994 < -1000$.

Comment: The OP specified that they were looking for ***hints on what to try***.